# Adding Word files to document

Tags: conversion, msword, word-to-latex

I am preparing a report using LaTeX and would like to add several documents saved as Word files. I have tried this before making each page a figure but I really don't like the results. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you can convert the word documents to pdf, you could use the `pdfpages` package to insert the pdf files into your document.

Comment: @Jan: Why don't you post that as an answer?

Comment: I just tried pdfpages and that package worked great. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

if you need the documents  as TeX source, then install a trial version of

- [grindeq](http://www.grindeq.com/) or convert it online
- [Word2TeX](http://www.word2tex.com/)
- install a virtuell pdf printer for later use of package `pdfpages` or simply the command `\includegraphics`

Comment: +1 for Word2TeX. The LaTeX file produced by Word2TeX is **very** clean, including the exported math.

Answer (score 7):

The `pdfpages` package, found [here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages?lang=en), is useful for appending PDF versions of the Word documents to LaTeX documents.

Originally suggested by @Jan Hlavacek in a comment, it should be an official answer.

Thank you to @Alan Munn for pointing out the `pagecommand` option to add page headers and numbers, as was posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89792/change-document-class-per-page).  The `[pagecommand={}]` option will maintain the normal page layout, as suggested by @Martin Scharrer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71427/include-several-pages-of-a-pdf-without-losing-latex-document-style).

You should also pay particular attention that the default `\includepdf{}` behaviour of this package is to only show the first page.  Adding the `[pages=-]` option includes all pages.  This has been addressed by @Mario S. E. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183469/includepdf-only-shows-first-page).

Comment: `pdfpages` most certainly can add headers and page numbers to included pages. See [Change document class per page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89792/2693) for an example.

Comment: @Alan Munn I stand corrected!  Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a [blog post comparing a number of different ways of converting documents to LaTeX format](http://www.charlietanksley.net/philtex/converting-to-latex/).

My two favorites are the LaTeX export routine of the OpenSource Word Processor [AbiWord](http://abisource.org) which can open a file in Word format and save as LaTeX (this uses the [wvWare libraries](http://wvware.sourceforge.net/) for conversion; make sure you install the extra export plugins and math support when you install), and the [rtf2latex2e](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rtf2latex2e/) converter which will convert RTF files to LaTeX (of course you must first export to RTF in Word).

If this is something you really care about, though, nothing will eliminate the need for going over the results and tweaking them as needed.

Comment: the export of AbiWord to LaTeX is only useful for _extremely_ (!) simple files

Comment: That's true, but I don't know of anything else that is free that is better. Writer2LaTeX is terrible by comparison. (IMHO of course.)

Comment: The link to the blog post is dead. [Wayback machine link](http://web.archive.org/web/20110828122410/http://www.charlietanksley.net/philtex/converting-to-latex/)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to obtain a LaTeX source would be to use [OpenOffice.org](http://openoffice.org) Writer with the [Writer2LaTeX](http://writer2latex.sourceforge.net/) extension. However, the resulting source will need some post-processing.