# Include 6 pages of a pdf with document's header and section title

Tags: pdfpages, embedding

So, with `pdfpages`'s `includepdf` one can include several pages of a pdf in the document. But this forces a pagebreak which leaves a lonely and unhappy section title.

```
\includepdf[nup=2x3, pages={6-}]{present.pdf}
```

Since internally `includepdf` uses `includegraphics` now can do

```
\fbox{\centering \includegraphics[page=6, scale=0.71]{present.pdf}}
```

To embed a page on the pdf.

However, how can we embed 2x3 pages?

I'm guessing I could do the `includegraphics` trick six times, but it's not very elegant. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71427/include-several-pages-of-a-pdf-without-losing-latex-document-style) help?

Comment: @ArTourter Yes Indeed! Damn, I should have read the pdfpages documentation more thoroughtly :S