# Include separate document as is, contents and all?

Tags: include

I have to include a whole separate document (some documentation) in with my main document, meaning title page, contents, page numbers and all. This seems to be similar to [How to include a document into another document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11311/how-to-include-a-document-into-another-document) but my understanding is that it won't include contents or similar

Is there a way to do this?

I can include the document as pictures if necessary, but i hope that it won't be

Comment: See this question: [Change documentclass per page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89792/2693).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Comment: Saying you can "include the document as pictures" suggests that it's already compiled into a pdf. That suggests that tools for including pdfs in LaTeX source or gluing pdfs together may solve your problem. If you give a little more detail (a MWE (minimal working example) illustrating your problem you may get more help.

Comment: What is the format of you separate document?