# How to embed a letter?

Tags: environments, letters

Suppose I am writing a novel using the book class, in which a correspondence from the hero to the heroine needs to be embeded, like this:

> Dear Marie,
>
> I miss you very much, I'll come home in a week.
>
> Yours,
>
> Joseph

How can this be done?

Comment: Can you be more specific in your question? It's nice to know how you write a letter. But what is your problem?

Comment: Hi CravingSpirit and [welcome to TeX.sx](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). In its current form, your question might not receive many answers. Please take a look at the [How to Ask](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)-page and try to improve your question according to the guidance found there. This may require you to show some effort on your part in terms of attempting a solution. If you have questions about what to do or if you don't quite understand what this means, please ask for clarification using the `add comment` function.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) If you're trying to typeset a letter, you can use, for instance, the `letter` class (see [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Letters)) or the more advanced [`scrlettr` class](http://www.ctex.org/documents/packages/nonstd/koma-script.pdf).

Comment: If your question is literally about inserting a letter into a document then [Change document class per page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89792/2693) is a duplicate and shows you how to do this. But in the context of writing a novel, I don't think this is what you want, so perhaps your question is simply about how best to create a letter environment within the novel that sets the letter text off from the rest of the novel. Is that your question?

Answer (score 7):

For some letter that easy, you can also stick to the `quote` environment as a base:

```
\documentclass{article}
%xetex specific ---- replace by any other font setting command depending on your engine
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\letterfont}{Comic Sans MS}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{letter}{%
\begin{quote}
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\letterfont
\BODY
\end{minipage}
}
\end{quote}
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{letter}
Dear Marie,

I miss you very much, I'll come home in a week.

Yours,

Joseph
\end{letter}
\lipsum[3-4]


\end{document}
```

[image]

PS: I used `XeLaTeX` and the `fontspec` package for font setting. But you can replace my definition of `\letterfont` with any other font setting command, that you can use with your engine.

Answer (score 4):

You can write your letter with, for example, the `letter` class :

```
\documentclass{letter}
\signature{Your name}
\address{Street \\ City \\ Country}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Company name \\ Street\\ City\\ Country}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam:}
\dots
\closing{Yours Faithfully,}
\ps{P.S. Here goes your ps.}
\encl{Enclosures.}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

(example from [texblog.org](http://texblog.org/2007/08/15/writing-a-letter-in-latex/))

and then include the pdf outpout in your main document using the `pdfpages` package :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages=-,
            pagecommand=\thispagestyle{fancy}
            %if you want to have headers and footers in the included pdf pages
]{my_lettre.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's nice. But what if the letter is a short one and not suitable for occupying a whole page?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: If it is a very short letter as your example, you can shape it manually in your main document with locally increasing spacing...  It depends of the formating you need.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using pdfTeX, there's a decently easy (although roundabout) way of doing this using `\includegraphics` and `pdfcrop` (standard with at least TeX Live)

```
\documentclass{letter}

\begin{document}
\signature{Joseph}

\begin{letter}{}

\opening{Dear Marie,}
I miss you very much, I'll come home in a week.
\closing{Yours,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

and then `pdfcrop letter.pdf`, which produces `letter-crop.pdf` which you can include thusly

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx,mwe}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{letter-crop}
\end{center}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

for the output

[image: output]