# Include a paper in a dissertation

Tags: sectioning, pdf, amsart, thesis

I'm start writing my dissertation and I want to include two papers that I wrote in the appendix. I want them to appear in the original format that they were written (amsart). I'm using a template provided by my uni for the dissertation. What's the best way for doing it in LaTeX? Or should I work only with the pdf file?

Comment: You should use the `pdfpages` package and include the PDFs versions of your article.  See [Change document class per page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89792) for an example. (Possible duplicate).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Feel free to visit our [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to get the most out of our site.