# How do I add my Vita to the end of my dissertation?

Tags: resume

Our grad school has a dissertation.cls and I've already put my vita into a res.cls. Is there any way that I can run these two things together? Here is what my code looks like:

```
\documentclass[phd,12pt]{psuthesis}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{exscale}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{eqlist} % Makes for a nice list of symbols.
\usepackage[final]{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{color}
```

etc. etc. and then at the very end I have this:

```
% Vita
\vita{SupplementaryMaterial/Vita}

\end{document}
```

However, in my Vita.tex file, it opens with

```
\documentclass{res} 
\setlength{\textheight}{9.5in} % increase text height to fit on 1-page 

\begin{document}
```

Is there any way that I can add my already made vita without reformatting it? Thanks.

Comment: This is easy to do with `pdfpages`.  See [Change document class per page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89792) for an example. If that solves your problem we can close your question as a duplicate.