# can I use two different classes in the same document?

Tags: document-classes

I need to use the `article` and `letter`, classes because I need
some of the functionality of `lettter` and some of  `article`.

Is it possible?
and, if yes, how?

Comment: What/from which do you need more, article or letter? What do you need from the two? As far as I know, there is no possibility to use two classes.

Comment: You can use class `scrartcl` with package `scrletter`. Since KOMA-Script version 3.23 it should be also possible to use `scrletter` with a standard class like `article`.

Comment: Related: [Change document class per page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89792/2693).  A lot depends on the specific things you want to do, so if you tell us more about the exact requirements we might be able to help.

Comment: what I need, is to made a leafletter A5 format, using A4 page (4 signature for page), printed front and back, with border line (I use tikz).
Inside leafletter I need to use some letter command (like \opening, \closing) but with the class I use this is impossible.