# Is it possible to create a memo "environment" after my title page, in an article class?

Tags: sectioning, document-classes

I'm writing a report right now (in an article class, I know.. But I didn't want to have a Chapter as my top level of organization), and the report guidelines specify a memorandum/letter of submittal after the title page.

I was wondering if it's possible to have an "environment" of a memo (TexMemo is one I saw a lot while googling this question) inside my article class.

[The screenshot of the memo on this page is an example of what I would like to create.](https://texblog.org/2012/03/07/writing-a-memo-in-latex/)
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. It's surely possible to do what you want to do, but without knowing more about what your letter/memo environment should look like, it's very hard to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks! @AlanMunn

https://texblog.org/2012/03/07/writing-a-memo-in-latex/ Just a basic memo like the one screenshotted here would suffice.  I'll edit this into the main post - thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @AlanMunn Upon more searching, with apparently better search terms, I found this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89792/change-document-class-per-page

which is another question you've answered.  I think this would fix my problem exactly.  Since the memo would be the first page after the title page, there's no issues with numbering.  Can you confirm that this is right?

Comment: Yes, I was going to link to that question. It does require two separate documents, but if this is a one off thing, and you independently like the linked memo style, it's a good solution, in which case we could close the question as a duplicate.