# \includepdf only shows first page

Tags: pdfpages

Using XeLaTeX I am trying to add a PDF to my file. Only the first page the PDF is included in the output file.

The following MWE refers to a PDF I created using Apple's TextEdit and 'Save as PDF' from the Print dialog. The contents are simply: 'Page 1', 'Page 2' etc. on each page.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\title{Minimal Working Example}
\date{}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Section 1}
Content

\includepdf{test-pdf}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) documentation, this is the default behavior when including pdfs with `\includepdf`.  In order to get all the pages, you need to type:

```
\includepdf[pages=-]{test-pdf}
```

Comment: Can this be the default somehow?

Comment: `\includepdfset{pages=-}` for setting global options

Answer (score 2):

I've observed the issue you describe **even with the `[pages=-]` option** provided. `pdflatex` worked as expected, but `xelatex` only included the first page, and even failed with an error if I explicitly set the page range to include the second page of my multi-page PDF:

```
Package pdfpages Error: page 2 of `142952.PDF' does not exist.
```

**The issue turned out to be triggered by an upper-case file extension (i.e., `.PDF`) on a case-sensitive file system**.

Changing the file name from `142952.PDF` to `142952.pdf` solved the problem with XeLaTeX. And of course, if the file extension is *lower-case* `.pdf`, it can also be omitted in the `\includepdf` argument.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Linux) it had problem when file contained `.` or `-` before `.pdf`. Renaming helped.