# Me too: \includepdf only shows first page

Tags: pdf, pdfpages, includegraphics, miktex2.9

I have the same problem as described by adam.baker in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/418212/includepdf-only-shows-first-page-despite-having-specifed-the-second-page/473759?noredirect=1#comment1194972_473759) post:

> \includepdf only shows first page, despite having multiple pages.

(This seems to be not limited to `pdfpages`, because `graphicx` with

`\includegraphics[page=2]{external}` also shows ONLY page 1.)

I have inserted my log file as answer in the original post.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

-Martin

[image]
[image]

Comment: You are using which LaTeX compiler: pdflatex, lualatex, xelatex? Try `\usepackage{mwe} ... \includegraphics[page=2]{example-image-a4-numbered}` and check if it works with that to make sure it is not your external file which is the problem.

Comment: Your system is not up-to-date. Run the miktex console update  as user to update the packages in your user tree.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: please refer to original post - the "external file" has been compiled as described there. Log shows compiler used (pdflatex). I tried your hints as well; shows only page one (black "1" on red ground). Both for `\includepdf` and `\includegraphics`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: thought so too - but MikTeX Console shows no updates available (both for user and admin). This is exactly as described in original post.

Comment: Your log shows outdated user packages in `Appdata\Roaming` (e.g. `C:\Users\Brennecke\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/pdfpages\pdfpages.sty`) but above the user installation goes to `AppData\Local`. That's rather odd. Ask in the miktex issue tracker, if and how you can correct the userinstall tree.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was due to a malfunctioning TeX distribution, solved by doing appropriate maintenance.

Comment: @egreg: not sure, if I understand the implications of what you are saying, but you are right - the problem was due to the distribution. (Note: previous version basic-miktex-2.9.6520-x64.exe was uninstalled via `Windows Control Panel/Programs and Features`; after that basic-miktex-2.9.6942-x64.exe was installed via `Run as administrator` and option "install for all users". No manual changes to any paths. Therefore I guess it is likely that somebody else might encounter something similar.)

Answer (score 2):

@UlrikeFischer: thank you very much indeed for pointing out the incorrect paths!
I was able to resolve the problem with the "cleanup" entry of MikTeX Console.
Just clicked "Reset personal MikTeX configuration" (it took a while for the operation to complete). After that it worked like a charm.

[image]

Thanks again a lot!