# How to export odt into latex?

Tags: conversion, open-office

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I convert Open Office documents into LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/768/how-do-i-convert-open-office-documents-into-latex)

Good morning

Somebody give me old document in doc or odt format and I would like to include them with mine which are latex documents. I see that some extension to openoffice or libreoffice exist in order to do that.

I am working under ubuntu 12.04 with libreoffice and the following package are available :

- libreoffice-writer2latex
- writer2latex
- openoffice.org-writer2latex
- libwriter2latex-java

The description of above package is the same, only the title change. Do you know which is the good one ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/768/how-do-i-convert-open-office-documents-into-latex?